# Angular. как в директиве выбрать templateUrl?

Tags: angularjs

Есть директива. Где в ней разместить логику выбора `templateUrl` исходя из переданных в нее параметров?

На пример:

```
<my-dir template="template-1"></div>
```

должна использовать в качестве templateUrl - 'myTemplate1.html', а

```
<my-dir template="none"></div>
```

не должна вообще использовать темплейт.

Comment: в обоих случаях эта директива не будет использовать _templateUrl_

Comment: можете подробнее рассказать, что именно вы хотите сделать, как выглядит ваша директива?

Comment: и как вы в примере из _"template-1"_ получили _'myTemplate1.html'_?

Comment: Grundy, к примеру так:

    if (template === 'template-1') {
      return "myTemplate1.html"
    } else {
      return;
    }

Comment: да, для этого случая - вполне подходит вариант из моего ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В зависимости от того, что вы хотите передавать как значение для атрибута *template* могут быть несколько ответов.

В случае если это просто имя, или часть имени, файла вы можете использовать [функцию как значение для поля *TemplateUrl*](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#template-expanding-directive)

```
templateUrl: function(elem, attrs){
    //должна вернуть URL для загрузки шаблона
    return attrs.template + ".html";
    //в первом вашем случае вернет "template-1.html"
}
```

так же вы можете проверить, что значение атрибута *none* и вернуть *undefined* или ничего не возвращать.

Comment: Отлично! А через scope никак?

Comment: @DenniLa2, во время выполнения функции _templateUrl_ скоп еще не инициализирован, поэтому внутри ее к нему и нет доступа